# html button does not become invisible

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, button

I want to set a button visibility based on what I retrieve from a session attribute in window.onload..
The alert appears so the button should become invisible.. Please let me know why it is still visible.

```
<button type="button" id="ex" onclick="">Ex</button>    
   <script>
    window.onload = function(){
          <%
          Object ex = session.getAttribute("ex");
          if (ex == null)
          {
             %>
             alert("NULL");
             document.getElementById('ex').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          <%     
          }
          else
          {
              %>
              alert("NOT NULL");
         <%   
          }
          %>
        
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: I wonder is your js running faster than the browser can render the html. If you put ```console.log(document.getElementById('ex'))``` after the alert does it pick it up?

Comment: Thanks. No, I just checked and the console log didn't appear. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Instead of using `window.onload`, use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { YOUR_CODE });`. You want to make sure the DOM finished loading before you start calling elements from it.

Comment: Theoretically speaking it should not be a problem with the element not being loaded, because a) the window `load` event *always* fires after `DOMContentLoaded` and b) the script is placed after the button, so the browser should render the button before executing the script.